# Why is this program not able to print right output for capital letters?

Tags: c, ascii

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  char a;
  printf("enter a letter");
  scanf("%c", & a);
  if (a >= 'A' || a <= 'Z') {
    a = a + 32;
  } else if (a >= 'a' || a <= 'z') {
    a = a - 32;
  }
  printf("%c", a);
  return 0;
}
```

The `if` condition is being properly executed, but what is wrong with the `else` condition?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `enter the alphabet`....nooooooo... it's the letter. all 26 combined is alphabet.

Comment: What's wrong with `tolower` and `toupper` ?

Comment: or `+=` and `-=`? Anyway, please learn the basic logical operators before asking on SO.

Answer (score 3):

You should change your condition to

```
if(a>='A' && a<='Z'){
    a=a+32;
}
else if(a>='a' && a<='z'){
    a=a-32;
}
```

To check *both* upper and lower bounds. Otherwise, `if (a>='A' || ....)` will *eat up* all the inputs for either uppercase or lowercase letters.

Comment: brother you are correct but can you explain more please

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the [ASCII codes](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/capital-letter-a-uppercase-ascii-code-65.html) of the alphabet. The uppercase letters begin with 65 for `A` through 97 for `Z`. The lower case starts with 97 for `a` through 122 for `z`.

Now, take your your conditional `if(a>='A'||a<='Z')`, it states *all values greater than or equal to `A` (65) **or** lower than or equal to `Z`* . This is a problem, because **every** ASCII code of any lowercase letter is **greater** than the code of `A`, that is, every lowercase letter is *greater* than `A`. Since this conditional uses an `||` (or) operator, everytime `a>='A'` is true, it will short-circuit and enter the body of your conditional.

In order to check for a **range** of letters, you should change it to:

```
if(a>='A' && a<='Z'){
    a=a+32;
}
else if(a>='a' && a<='z'){
    a=a-32;
}
```

Now, your conditional uses the `&&` (and) operator, which **must** evaluate to true **both** parts, `a>='A'` **and** `a<='Z'`, in order to enter the body of the conditional. This way, you make sure that the letter being checked, lies in the specified uppercase or lowercase ranges.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flip the case, and you entered uppercase letter, second 'if' will be bypassed because of 'else'.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **||** you should have used **&&**. This will bound the condition you are putting. Snippet shown below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  char a;
  printf("enter the alphabet");
  scanf("%c", & a);
  if (a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z') {
     a = a + 32;
  } 
   else if (a >= 'a' && a <= 'z') {
     a = a - 32;
  }
  printf("%c", a);
  return 0;
}
```